# Suddenly Devise gem crashed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Everything was fine, but suddenly my application started crashing and didn't starts.

Here is my log:

```
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic
   _matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `after_sign_up_path_for' for #<Class:0x4422480> (NameError)
```

and other errors below are related with this.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse me, I found my error. I was caused by calling method wrongly.